# Javascript "if" with "or" How check which will exec

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if (a != 1 || b != 2) {
  console.log(this, ' is required');
}
```

Can we get the answer `a is required` or `b is required`?

Comment: Why not have two different ifs?

Comment: You need to use multiple if statements.

Comment: because I want check many parameter 10 or 20 - and i dont want 10 ifs

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the answer from variable that executed but I have another way to do.

```
var array = [{name:"a",value:2,checkvalue:1},{name:"b",value:3,checkvalue:2}];

for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
  if(array[i].value!=array[i].checkvalue){
    console.log(array[i].name + "is required!");
  }
}
```

try this. I hope it can be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is what you want. If not, add more information.

```
function checkVariable(variable, value){
  if(variable!=value) return variable+" is required";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work, too:

```js
const a = document.getElementById('a')
const b = document.getElementById('b')
let c;

function evaluateAB() {
  c = "";
  if((Number(a.value) != 1 && (c="a")) || (Number(b.value) != 2 && (c="b"))){
    console.log(c ? c + ' is required' : void(0));
  }
}
```

```html
<label>a: <input type="number" value="0" id="a" /></label>
<label>b: <input type="number" value="0" id="b" /></label>
<button type="button" onclick="evaluateAB()">Evaluate</button>
```

Comment: How will that look for 20 variables, which OP commented there might be?

Comment: @LGSon Ugly... very ugly. Just hoping this gives some inspiration.